# How to check if a column exists in Impala table?

Tags: impala

I have created an external table in Impala. I am writing a shell script which checks whether a particular column exists in that table.

We can do this in MySql using the following query.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

But, in Impala, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot query the schema metadata in Impala. You can use `describe table` (see [the documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_describe.html)) and check the output.

Answer (score 2):

There is [SHOW Statement](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html) in [Cloudera Impala](https://www.cloudera.com/products/apache-hadoop/impala.html):

> The SHOW statement is a flexible way to get information about different types of Impala objects.

For your use case you can use [SHOW COLUMN STATS Statement](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html#show_column_stats), e.g.:

```
SHOW COLUMN STATS myTableName
```

It will return following information:

```
+------------------------+--------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| Column                 | Type   | #Distinct Values | #Nulls | Max Size | Avg Size |
+------------------------+--------+------------------+--------+----------+----------+
| my_column_id           | INT    | -1               | -1     | 4        | 4        |
| my_string_column_name  | STRING | -1               | -1     | -1       | -1       |
| some_column_name       | INT    | -1               | -1     | 4        | 4        |
...
```